# Short embedded dialogs - how to indent the second (and subsequent) line(s)

Tags: alignment

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,8pt,english,]{extbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{EBGaramond-Regular}
\usepackage[papersize={4.80 in, 6.40  in},left=.5 in,right=.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filright}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Blind text}

\lipsum[6-3]
\medskip

\begingroup
\leftskip\parindent
\rightskip\leftskip
\noindent \textsc{beneš}: Impossible!

\noindent \textsc{masaryk}: That sow Sir Horace Wilson's going too. Wilson's
going too. Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too. WWilson's going too.
Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too.
ilson's going too. Wilson's...
\par
\endgroup
\medskip

\lipsum[5-3]

\end{document}
```

When a dialog item such as 'MASARYK: That sow Sir Horace... etc.' above is too long to fit on a single line, I would like to have the second (and subsequent) line(s) indented further:

```
<indented by default value of \\parindent>MASARYK:first line on same line as character's name...
                                             <second line, indented>
                                             <third line indented & aligned with second line>
    ... etc.
```

Besides... whenever there is more than one line of dialog, I would prefer the block to be left- & right-justified.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

**Update**

Here's an image to clarify:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

The following is probably closer to the expected output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,8pt,english,]{extbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]{EBGaramond-Regular}
\usepackage[papersize={4.80 in, 6.40  in},left=.5 in,right=.5 in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\filright}{}{0pt}{\Large}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newenvironment{dialogue}
    {\begin{adjustwidth}{\parindent}{\parindent}\medskip \begin{description}[font=\normalfont\scshape, noitemsep]}
    {\end{description}\end{adjustwidth}\medskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Blind text}

\lipsum[6-3]

\begin{dialogue}
\item[beneš:] Impossible!
\item[masaryk:] That sow Sir Horace Wilson's going too. Wilson's
going too. Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too. WWilson's going too.
Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too. Wilson's going too.
ilson's going too. Wilson's...
\end{dialogue}

\lipsum[5-3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Splendid. Does exactly what I needed.